# Railroad diagrams - what do the double bars on the ends mean?

Tags: json

In the [json](https://www.json.org/) site, the number and string diagrams are book-ended by double bars.

What do the double bars mean?

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/number.gif))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/string.gif))</sub>

Comment: They appear to represent start/end of the diagram. Is this a trick question?

Comment: Hmm. Never noticed that before... +1.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Go to json.org and look at the other diagrams: they all have single bars. Why the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- One bar: whitespace can be inserted between pairs of tokens.
- Two bars: no whitespace allowed between pairs of tokens.

Comment: Hmm. What about the array image? (http://json.org/array.gif) There is WS allowed in that (around '[', ',', and ']') but it doesn't seem to be noted. And two string tokens never occur together...

Comment: @Thanatos I don't understand your question: the array image has single bars at each end, which shows whitespace is indeed allowed, as (I think) you're also saying?

Comment: Oh. Hmm. While I did misread that, I still don't quite get it. These are both valid JSON: `[  [  1 ,  2 ]  ]` and `[ "hi there"  ,  "more space?"  ]`

Comment: @Thanatos: yes. The single bars on array indicate that the whitespace between your brackets, numbers and strings is allowed.

Comment: Thanks.  At the bottom of the page, there is a statement: "Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens".  Perhaps that should be amended?

Answer (score 1):

Single bars denote an element that is a "first-class" element (e.g. object, value), double bars delimit an element that is a subcomponent of another.