# JSON grammar definition notation

Tags: json, schema, state-machine

[image]

What is the name of this kind of notation? It seems like a Finite State Machine.

Comment: It *describes* a FSM, somewhat loosely. I think it's just a generic [state diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Railroad diagrams - what do the double bars on the ends mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986518/railroad-diagrams-what-do-the-double-bars-on-the-ends-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax diagrams (or **railroad diagrams**) are a way to represent **a context-free grammar**. They represent a graphical alternative to Backus–Naur form or to EBNF as metalanguages.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram